# bloomberg beqs response elements

Tags: excel, request, bloomberg, vba

I'm using excel vba to send beqsrequest and handle response. The bloomberg developer's guide says BeqsResponse message has responseError and securityData element. When handling the response, I used

```
Dim securities As blpapicomLib2.Element
Set securities = message.GetElement("securityData")
```

I got run-time error 5 - invalid procedure call or argument. However it worked when I put

```
Dim securi As blpapicomLib2.Element
Set securi = message.GetElement("responseError")
```

What's wrong with "securityData" ? And is there a way to get all the elements from message using blpapicomLib2 ?
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the error on that specific line (`Set securities = message.GetElement("securityData")`) or later on when you use the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top level `securityData` is an array of `securityData` elements:

[image]

So you need to do something similar to a ReferenceDataResponse, for which you can find several examples in the doc, such as in "4.4 - Response Details".

Comment: In Response Details, "Element securityDataArray = ReferenceDataResponse.getElement("securityData");" is used. And my message.AsElement.NumElements gave me 1. Was it because of the request? Beqs request asks for equities screened by the user under certain screen names? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have never used eqs from the api to be honest. But the Response diagram is similar to RefDataResponse so should work the same way - unless they made an error in the doc...

Comment: It worked. Beqsresponse.AsElement.NumElements = 1. And the element is "data" somehow. "securityData" element is subelement of "data".